WordPress AJAX returning 'Invalid JSON response' after sending data to external API with wp_remote_post
I'm working on a WordPress-based project that involves sending data via an AJAX request to a Lambda function using the wp_remote_post() method. The request includes JWT authentication and CSRF token validation.
Everything works fine implementation CSRF token, but when I added the CSRF token validation I encounter this error in the browser console:
{
   "code": "invalid_json",
   "message": "The response is not a valid JSON response."
}

Here's the function that processes the AJAX request in PHP:
function lambda_api_request() {

check_ajax_referer('lambda_api_nonce', '_ajax_nonce');

$formData = isset($_POST['formData']) ? json_decode(wp_unslash($_POST['formData']), true) : [];

if (empty($formData)) {
    wp_send_json_error('No form data received');
    return;
}

$csrf_token = isset($formData['csrf_token']) ? $formData['csrf_token'] : '';

if (!wp_verify_nonce($csrf_token, 'contact_form_7_csrf')) {
    wp_send_json_error('Invalid CSRF token');
    return;
}

$url = 'https://api-endpoint.com';
$jwt_token = get_option('lambda_jwt_token', '');
$api_key = get_option('lambda_api_key', '');

if (empty($jwt_token)) {
    wp_send_json_error('JWT token not defined');
    return;
}

$response = wp_remote_post($url, [
    'method'    => 'POST',
    'headers'   => [
        'x-api-key'    => $api_key,
        'x-api-jwt'    => $jwt_token,
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ],
    'body'      => json_encode($formData),
    'timeout'   => 35,
]);

if (is_wp_error($response)) {
    $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
    wp_send_json_error($error_message);
} else {
    $response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);

    // Verify JSON response
    $decoded_response = json_decode($response_body, true);
    if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        wp_send_json_success($decoded_response);
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error('Invalid JSON response from the API.');
    }
   }
  }

  add_action('wp_ajax_lambda_api_request', 'lambda_api_request');
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_lambda_api_request', 'lambda_api_request');

What I've Tried:
Checked Nonce and CSRF validation: The nonce and CSRF token are properly generated and passed with the form data.
Checked the server response: Using browser developer tools, the response shows the "Invalid JSON response" message.
Logging output: The API URL, JWT token, and API key are being retrieved correctly, and the form data is being sent as expected. I logged these values using error_log(), and they appear correct.
Why do I get an "Invalid JSON response" error when calling wp_remote_post() and why doesn't it work with the token when I check it when sending the request? Any suggestions on how to debug or resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
